# Does httptrace allow to track when a connection is closed and/or returned back to the pool?

Tags: http, go

I want to capture some statistics on the connection pool which backs the http client. Is it possible to track when a connection is closed or returned to the pool using the [`httptrace`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptrace) package?

I have this contrived example (doesn't work on go playground because of the http request):

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptrace"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    trace := &httptrace.ClientTrace{
        GotConn: func(info httptrace.GotConnInfo) {
            log.Printf("GotConn(%+v)", info)
        },
        PutIdleConn: func(err error) {
            log.Printf("PutIdleConn(%+v)", err)
        },
    }

    client := http.DefaultClient

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://golang.org/", nil)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        ctx := httptrace.WithClientTrace(req.Context(), trace)
        req = req.WithContext(ctx)

        res, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if _, err := io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, res.Body); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        res.Body.Close()

        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
    }

    time.Sleep(1000 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Which prints:

```
2021/09/03 13:41:40 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:false WasIdle:false IdleTime:0s})
2021/09/03 13:41:40 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.389029ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:40 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.305419ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:40 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.874064ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:40 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.303527ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:41 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.815831ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:41 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.679228ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:41 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.580963ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:41 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.95814ms})
2021/09/03 13:41:41 GotConn({Conn:0xc00020a000 Reused:true WasIdle:true IdleTime:10.788015ms})
```

The problem is that `PutIdleConn` is never called, even though we can see the connection is being reused.

I've expected that `PutIdleConn` will be called when the connection is returned back to the pool, possibly with an error, is the pool is full and then connection needs to be closed.

Related, is it possible to tell that the connection was closed using `httptrace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation of PutIdleConn hook](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptrace@go1.17#ClientTrace) for `go 1.17` says it's not currently used for HTTP/2, and the response for `https://golang.org/` is `HTTP/2.0`, try logging it with

```
log.Printf("Got response with proto: %s", res.Proto)
```

Comment: Thanks, indeed documentation is quite clear on http2 :) Do you know what about the connection closing? I don't see anything in the docs so I assume its not possible either.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, I was not able to find any hook for connection closing